# setFont() method not working on label as expected javafx

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am creating a short javafx program containing a label with some text and a button which is supposed to change the font of the label to italic. Since the font I use is a custom font, I can't directly call `new Font("human.ttf", FontPosture.ITALIC, 20)` as javafx can't convert a custom font to italic or bold.

So I decided to have two different font files with the same font family with one having regular style and the other having italic style. Thus, when the italic button is clicked, the program would load the italic font file and set the font of the label to be the italic font.

But when I tried the program, the font of the label remains unaffected after clicking the italic button. I tried hard to find the source of the issue and added several print statements. During the process I found the problem was that the setFont method in the eventHandler of the button was not working correctly. Due to the print statements I also found that the font file path was correct. Hence, I am unable to figure out my mistake in the code.

This is the FontChanger class:

```
public class FontChanger extends Application{

    private Label label;

    private Font font;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        root.setPrefHeight(30);
        root.setPrefWidth(30);
        addLabel(root);
        addItalicButton(root);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void addLabel(AnchorPane root){
        label = new Label("Sample text");
        font = Font.loadFont(FontChanger.this.getClass().getResource("human.ttf").toExternalForm    (), 20);
        label.setFont(font);
        label.setLayoutX(10);
        label.setLayoutY(10);
        root.getChildren().add(label);
    }


    public void addItalicButton(AnchorPane root){
        Button italicButton = new Button("italic");
        italicButton.setLayoutX(10);
        italicButton.setLayoutY(35);
        italicButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                font = Font.loadFont(FontChanger.this.getClass().getResource("human_italic.ttf").toExternalForm(), 20);
                System.out.println(FontChanger.this.getClass().getResource("human_italic.ttf").to    ExternalForm());
                label.setFont(font);
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(italicButton);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Please tell me if any kind of clarification is needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after hours of experimentation, I have found that the problem is that whenever the font of a label or any similar control is already set to a custom font, you cannot set it once again to another custom font. I don't know the reason why this happens.

You cannot do this:

```
public void setFont(){
    Font firstCustomFont = Font.loadFont(FontChanger.this.getClass().getResource("firstCustomFont.ttf").toExternalForm(), 20);
    label.setFont(firstCustomFont);
    Font secondCustomFont = Font.loadFont(FontChanger.this.getClass().getResource("secondCustomFont.ttf").toExternalForm(), 20);
    label.setFont(secondCustomFont);// this will not work
}
```

I also found that you could set the font of a label to be a normal font after setting it to a custom font. And also you could set the font to a custom font if it is already set to a local font.

These two examples will work:

```
public void setFont(){
    Font customFont = Font.loadFont(FontChanger.this.getClass().getResource("customFont.ttf").toExternalForm(), 20);
    label.setFont(customFont);
    Font normalFont = Font.font(20);
    label.setFont(normalFont);// this will work
}
```

And:

```
public void setFont(){
    Font normalFont = Font.font(20);
    label.setFont(normalFont);
    Font customFont = Font.loadFont(FontChanger.this.getClass().getResource("customFont.ttf").toExternalForm(), 20);
    label.setFont(customFont);// this will work
}
```

So the trick I applied is that I first set the font of the label to a local font and then setting the font once again to the custom font you want to be set.

Something like this:

```
public void setFont(){
    Font firstCustomFont = Font.loadFont(FontChanger.this.getClass().getResource("firstCustomFont.ttf").toExternalForm(), 20);
    label.setFont(font);
    Font normalFont = Font.font(20);
    label.setFont(normalFont);
    Font secondCustomFont = Font.loadFont(FontChanger.this.getClass().getResource("secondCustomFont.ttf").toExternalForm(), 20);
    label.setFont(secondFont);// this will work
}
```

**Edit:**  This problem occurred because the font files I used were the edited                          versions of the same font family. So this method could work pretty well if you have a regular and styled version of a font file and then you want to apply the styled version to a text which is already set to the regular version.

Comment: Interesting: that looks like a bug. `Label.setFont` will delegate to the `fontProperty().set(...)` method. If the supplied font is equal (in the sense of `.equals(...)`) to the current font, the method becomes a no-op. `Font` defines `.equals(...)` to compare the name and size of the font; so if the name assigned to the custom fonts are the same, then I think that is why this fails. What do `firstCustomFont.getName()` and `secondCustomFont.getName()` return?

Comment: Yea, you are right. They return the same value. This is because the font files I use are edited versions of the same font file. So this is the area I think  I failed to consider. Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: So if you could add some kind of versioning to the file name somehow....